# Celery BROKER_URL with vhosts not properly recognized

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a problem connecting to a RabbitMQ vhost via BROKER_URL. My vhost name is navarro which rabbitmqctl shows:

```
 $ rabbitmqctl list_vhosts
 /
 navarro
 $
```

However, with

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/navarro'
```

I get `error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer` and `"access to vhost '/' refused for user 'guest'"` in my logfile (guest is only configured for my vhost, note it is not the auth issue but the vhost issue that is the problem).

If I use

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//navarro'
```

I get

```
"access to vhost '/navarro' refused for user 'guest'"
```

which makes sense since there is no vhost `/navarro`. But how do I connect to the actual host `navarro`?

Writing this I got the idea to allow the user guest also on '/', will let you know whether it helps.

Well it helps because the tasks ends up in the '/' vhost and not in the navarro one. However, starting Celery with the app connects to the correct queue. I thought both locations are defined by the same setting.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to comment, so leaving an answer.

Are you sure that the user `guest` has permissions on the vhost? What did you do to make sure he does?

You could run:

`rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p navarro guest ".*" ".*" ".*"`

Your first way of getting to the vhost is the correct one (only one `/`).